# Magento 2 module version number not editable

Tags: magento2, module, error, configuration

I have just started exploring Magento 2 structure and code-flow, also module development.

When I created module from an online module generator and tried to change it's `"setup_version"` & "`schema_version"` in "module.xml" (doesn't matter if I increase or decrease version, it should be changeable as needed, I guess) and then if I follow all processes of compiling and enabling the module after flushing caches, it generates error as below on running the website:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:279:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Company1_Module1 schema: current version - 2.0.0, required version - 1.0.0
Company1_Module1 data: current version - 2.0.0, required version - 1.0.0";i:1;s:3447:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
```

Below is my `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Company1_Module1" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0" data_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

I know `"data_version"` is not needed but I did it for trial and error checks, still it gives error as above.

Need urgent assistance and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Only **`setup_version`** is required. **`schema_version`** and **`data_version`** is obsolete.
2. Right now magento2 does not support downgrading. You have `current version - 2.0.0` which is the version of the module in the `setup_module` table, and you are attempting to downgrade to `1.0.0`. This is not supported. Please update this record in the database directly, or uninstall module using `bin/magento module:uninstall Company1_Module1` and then reinstall and enable via `bin/magento module:enable`. Of course, you will have to run compile, and regenerate static files etc.

Comment: Just did and it started working for now, but have to wait until a proper solution is discovered.

Comment: "but have to wait until a proper solution is discovered." Can you please elaborate on that? Solution to what?

Answer (score 0):

To enable your module you need to do as below :

go to the CLI and then the root folder of your magento installation and run the below command :

`php magento bin/setup:upgrade`

Comment: Already done, also did "di:compile", anyways that problem is no longer there, I am getting another issue of "Object domdocument should be created" when I run my module in browser like "http://192.168.0.106/magento-2/module1/index/index". Any suggestions for that ?

Comment: Upgrade will not work in this case. As you can see that the current version(2.0.0) is higher than the required version(1.0.0). Need a downgrade instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove you module with command `bin/magento module:uninstall Company1_Module1` and than add with `bin/magento module:enable Company1_Module1`

Answer (score 0):

Your module version in database is 2.0.0. And you are trying to upgrade to version 1.0.0 from 2.0.0, which is wrong. So one thing you can do is change your version number in DB to 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is delete the row from 'setup_module' and run setup:upgrade again. (if you are creating any tables or adding any columns in your setup script make sure you have if exists or some sort of check in your script to ensure it doesn't try to recreate the data, or simply delete the table/columns it creates as well and then run setup:upgrade. This will set your module version correctly in database so when you do an upgrade script it will change the version to whatever you decide.